# There seem to be severe issues with Mathematica 12.1 running System Modeler models and with WSM 12.1 itself on Windows 10

Tags: warning-messages, windows, system-modeler, system-modeling

I am using Wolfram Mathematica 12.1 and the Wolfram System Modeler 12.1 on a Windows 10 (64 Bit) notebook. Pretty much exactly since yesterday (2020-04-10), I am experiencing severe and previously unknown issues with running models in System Modeler and Mathematica.

**Minimum Example**

```
$Version
(* "12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

SystemModelSimulate[
    SystemModel["DocumentationExamples.Simulation.WeakAxis"]
] // Head
```

> `SystemModelSimulate`

We should of course have gotten `SystemModelSimulationData`. During the evaluation the following error messages are given:

> `SystemModelSimulate::bld` : Failed to build model DocumentationExamples.Simulation.WeakAxis.
>
> `SystemModelSimulate::bldI` : Internal error: Stack overflow

I am getting the internal error message also for validating elementary classes in WSM 12.1 and when trying to run introductory example models in WSM 12.1 Simulation Center.

Is anybody else experiencing these errors? Since over the easter break I will not be able to reach WRI or MathCore: Have you found a fix? (Maybe a Windows 10 update is the culprit here?)

**Update**

I tested on a separate Windows computer using my home license and there the example worked. So it seems that one can narrow down this issue to cases, where WSM and Mathematica are installed on the same machine. This predominantly appears to be a Wolfram System Modeler issue.

Comment: No problem in Linux, using Version 12.1.

Comment: @Rolf Could you possibly clarify: Are there no problems in both, WSM and Mma, in Linux?

Comment: Works fine on macOS 10.15.4 with MMA V12.1 (I don't have WSM).

Comment: @gwr Yes WSM12.1 & M12.1 on Linux: no problem.

Comment: Can you try unloading all models that are not shipped with SystemModeler and try again? Maybe some other model is interfering with all model builds somehow.

Comment: @Malte Yes, that solves the issue. Some model I had added recently must "break validation". Very strange.

Comment: @gwr yes, it is certainly a bug in System Modeler then. If you can narrow down which model is causing the issue (or are willing to share all of them), feel free to send them to me, and I will make sure the bug is fixed.